# scilab save('-append') doesn't seem to work

Tags: hdf5, large-data, scilab

I am trying to create a dataset for ML using Scilab, and I need to save during data generation because it's too big for scilab's max stack.
Here is a toy example I made to find out what goes wrong but I'm not able to figure it out

```
datas=[];
labels=[];
for i =1:10
    for j=1:100
        if j==1
            disp(i)
        end
        data = sin(-%pi:0.01:%pi);
        label = rand();
        datas = [datas, data];
        labels = [labels, label];
    end
    save(chemin+'\test.h5','-append','datas','labels')
    datas = [];
    labels = [];
end
```

I am looking for the shape of data to be [1000,629] at the end, but I get [62900,0]

Have you any ideas why it is?

Comment: The option `-append` looks more like in a shell environment. What about `append`?

Comment: @Friedrich the '-append' comes from scilab's doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to incrementally save a big matrix without any memory pressure:

```
// create a new HDF5 file
a = h5open(TMPDIR + "/test.h5", "w")

// create the dataset

N = 3; // number of chuncks
nrows = 5;  // rows of a single chunk
ncols = 10; // cols of a single chunk
chsize = [nrows, ncols];
maxrows = N*nrows; // final number of rows of concatenated matrix
maxcols = ncols;   // final number of cols of concatenated matrix


for k=1:N
    // warning, x is viewed as a C-matrix (row-major), transpose if applicable
    x = rand(nrows,ncols);
    h5dataset(a, "My_Dataset", ...
              [chsize ;1 1 ;1 1 ;chsize ;chsize],...
              x, ...
              [k*nrows ncols; maxrows maxcols; 1+(k-1)*nrows 1 ;1 1 ;chsize; chsize])
    h5dump(a, "My_Dataset");
end

disp(a.root.My_Dataset.data)

h5close(a)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly after little adaptation. I had to disable h5dump, which caused java heap to overflow

Comment: Indeed, the hd5dump was here just to show the successive changes of the dataset for this (tiny) example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to vertically concatenate (semicolon) instead of horizontally (coma)

```
datas = [datas; data];
labels = [labels; label];
```

BTW this won't solve your memory problem as the matrices grow in Scilab's workspace and using "-append" just owerwrites the objects in the hdf5 file (you are using the same names).

Comment: thank you for your anwser, do you know any other way to incrementaly save a matrix ?
I was using some arbitrary formating and using mfprintf() but it require knowing the format used when reading the data elsewhere

Comment: The only way to do this is to use low-level hdf5 commands in Scilab (namely, `h5write` and `h5dataset`).

Comment: Did you test my last answer ? To me, it solves your problem (and is the only way to do it without loosing precision and without memory pressure).